# Yum failing: Requires installed packages

Tags: rhel, package-management, yum

I have recently installed Red Hat RHEL 7 on an x86_64 machine and yum has been failing for some packages with similar (strange) output.

Here is one example, when trying to install gcc:

```
Error: Package: gcc-4.8.5-11.el7.x86_64 (rhel-7-desktop-rpms)
           Requires: cpp = 4.8.5-11.el7
           Installed: cpp-4.8.5-14.el7.x86_64 (@anaconda/7.4)
               cpp = 4.8.2-16.el7
               cpp = 4.8.5-14.el7
           Available: cpp-4.8.2-16.el7.x86_64 (rhel-7-desktop-rpms)
               cpp = 4.8.2-16.el7
           Available: cpp-4.8.2-16.2.el7_0.x86_64 (rhel-7-desktop-rpms)
               cpp = 4.8.2-16.2.el7_0
           Available: cpp-4.8.3-9.el7.x86_64 (rhel-7-desktop-rpms)
               cpp = 4.8.2-16.el7
               cpp = 4.8.3-9.el7
           Available: cpp-4.8.5-4.el7.x86_64 (rhel-7-desktop-rpms)
               cpp = 4.8.2-16.el7
               cpp = 4.8.5-4.el7
           Available: cpp-4.8.5-11.el7.x86_64 (rhel-7-desktop-rpms)
               cpp = 4.8.2-16.el7
               cpp = 4.8.5-11.el7
```

Here is the output from:

> sudo yum repolist

```
Loaded plugins: langpacks, product-id, search-disabled-repos, subscription-manager
repo id                                              repo name                                                     status
epel/x86_64                                          Extra Packages for Enterprise Linux 7 - x86_64                11,777
rhel-7-desktop-optional-rpms/7Client/x86_64          Red Hat Enterprise Linux 7 Desktop - Optional (RPMs)          12,365
rhel-7-desktop-rpms/7Client/x86_64                   Red Hat Enterprise Linux 7 Desktop (RPMs)                     11,673
repolist: 35,815
```

I have tried

> sudo yum cleanall

> sudo yum update

Answer (score 0):

cpp-4.8.5-11 is the version shipped with RHEL 7.3, but cpp-4.8.5-14 is shipped with RHEL 7.4 (which is still in beta, I believe). "Installed: cpp-4.8.5-14.el7.x86_64 (@anaconda/7.4)" indicates the installed version is a RHEL 7.4 package.

So I'm guessing you used installation media for RHEL 7.4, but the repository you're connecting to has RHEL 7.3 packages. If that's the problem, you'll want to configure a repo file in /etc/yum.repos.d for a RHEL 7.4 repository.

One possibility is copying an ISO for the installation media you used to your system, and configuring that as a local repository, until there's a RHEL 7.4 repository available through your network.